# Ubuntu 17.10 - Incorrect RAM count after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ram

I upgraded my 16.04 system to 17.10 yesterday, and I've now noticed that the system only recognizes 16GB of RAM. I have 28GB of RAM, which is recognized within BIOS. The RAM was properly showing as 28GB prior to the upgrade. I know this because I run a VM that requires 12GB of RAM, and it won't even start at the moment due to the incorrect RAM readings.

Is the only option to reinstall 16.04? I've found nothing on the web related to this at all, and so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C memory`?